# Уменьшит ли это нагрузку на процессор?

Tags: php, mysql

У меня на сайте генерируется xml-файл. 
Выборку я сделал через цикл `for` кусками по 50 тыс записей за цикл (ранее была выборка сразу всех записей).

На данный момент у меня процессор нагружается на 90%, а озу только на 25%.

Вопрос: если я скрипт генератора xml перенесу на отдельный сервер, который будет питаться через mysql удаленно и выгружать файл потом на основной сервер обратно, то это снизит нагрузку на основной процессор или процессор также будет нагружен, т.к тут все равно будет подключение к MYSQL, хоть и удаленное ?

Comment: у вас вопрос получился примерно вида "если я напишу код по-другому, это поможет?"  нужны детали того, как у вас организована работа сейчас. Какого объема этот файл, как вы его формируете, как запрашиваете данные. Кешируете ли вы его, и как часто он обновляется.
Может вы там на каждую строку файла отдельный запрос пишите, а мы тут гадать будем почему все долго и медленно.

Comment: Да пока вообще непонятно, кто читает эти куски по 50к записей и генерит XML... и вот сдаётся мне, что это ни разу не MySQL.

Comment: А что именно грузит процессор ? Любая ОС точно показывает какие процессы грузят процессор. Если его грузит именно процесс, а MySQL при этом практически отдыхает, то конечно унос процесса на другой сервер снимет нагрузку.